# struct inode_operations permission function arguments

Tags: c, linux, file-io, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to implement permission management for my device driver and found the following [official Kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/vfs.html#id1) related to `struct inode_operations`:

```
struct inode_operations {
        //...
        int (*permission) (struct inode *, int);
        //...
};
```

The documentation for the `permission` function:

> called by the VFS to
>   check for access rights on a POSIX-like filesystem.
>
> May be called in rcu-walk mode (mask & MAY_NOT_BLOCK). If in rcu-walk
>   mode, the filesystem must check the permission without blocking or
>   storing to the inode.
>
> If a situation is encountered that rcu-walk cannot handle, return
>   `-ECHILD` and it will be called again in ref-walk mode.

It is not obvious what the function arguments mean. The first one is related to the `inode` associated with a file, but how about the second one?

Where is the meaning of the second argument of the function `int (*permission) (struct inode *, int);` documented?

UPD: I found several macros that seem to be related to the function's second argument at [`linux/fs.h`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/fs.h#L95)

```
#define MAY_EXEC        0x00000001
#define MAY_WRITE       0x00000002
#define MAY_READ        0x00000004
#define MAY_APPEND      0x00000008
#define MAY_ACCESS      0x00000010
#define MAY_OPEN        0x00000020
#define MAY_CHDIR       0x00000040
/* called from RCU mode, don't block */
#define MAY_NOT_BLOCK       0x00000080
```

Judging by the values it is exactly what the second argument mean, but it is completely unclear how to understand it without accidentally founding it in the source code...

Comment: I believe [you are](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/namei.c#L417) right, indeed documentation could be better.

Comment: @KamilCuk very interesting, thanks. It looks like it is also useful as a basis when implementing a custom `permission` function.